# Validação com DataAnnotation

Tags: c#, dataannotations

Estou querendo fazer uma validação com o tamanho de um campo do tipo `int` utilizando o DataAnnotation, usei o `[MaxLengthAttribute(10)]`, só no momento que vou fazer a `View` Index para trazer a lista dos itens cadastrados, retorna um erro.

Este é meu código:

```
[Display(Name = "RE")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "informe o RE")]
[MaxLengthAttribute(10)]
public int usuRE { get; set; }
```

Este é o erro:

> "There was an error running the select code generator: 'Unable to
>   retrieve metadata for 'LoginUser.Models.Usuario'. The property 'useRE'
>   is not a String or Byte array. Length can only be configured for
>   String and Byte array properties.'"

Tem alguma outra forma de eu conseguir fazer validação do tamanho deste campo utilizando o DataAnnotation? 
Um colega falou que eu poderia levar o `[MaxLengthAttribute(10)]` para o HTML e fazer essa validação lá, mas eu não sei como fazer isso, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Olá @Rafael. Coloque o seu código estruturado na sua questão ao invés de postar imagens. O mesmo para a mensagem de erro.

Comment: Ok, pode deixar, na próxima vez farei isso, desculpe!

Comment: Pode fazer já! Edite a sua questão e coloque o código :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No seu caso o `MaxLengthAttribute` não vai funcionar porque, como o próprio erro indica, apenas se aplica aos tipos `String` ou *array* de `Byte`.

Tem duas formas de contornar o problema:

**1.** Ao invés de utilizar o tipo `int`, passar para `string` e então utilizar o `[MaxLengthAttribute(10)]`, mas aí poderá ter implicações indesejadas na base de dados:

```
[Display(Name = "RE")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "informe o RE")]
[MaxLengthAttribute(10)]
public string usuRE { get; set; }
```

**2.** Se o objetivo for permitir valores de `0` a `9.999.999.999` (tamanho = 10), então terá que alterar o tipo para `long`, visto que o máximo do `int` é **`2.147.483.647`**:

```
[Display(Name = "RE")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "informe o RE")]
[Range(0, 9999999999)]
public long usuRE { get; set; }
```

Comment: Mas e se eu quiser que o usuário informe um RE com no mínimo 4 dígitos? Preciso que o RE tenha no mínimo 4 dígitos e no máximo 10

Comment: Aí basta alterar o range para (1000, 9999999999), visto que o número mínimo de 4 dígitos é 1000.

Answer (score 5):

A DataAnnotation **MaxLengthAttribute** é utilizada para limitar o tamanho de strings.

Para definir uma faixa de valores para propriedades inteiras, você deve utilizar a DataAnnotation **Range**, conforme abaixo:

```
[Range(18,65)]
public int Idade { get; set; }
```